# AppSync GraphQL using string based queries instead of generated types

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

I'm integrating AWS AppSync in my Android app but would like to use GraphQL query strings over the generated query types. This is because the queries being used may change at runtime and I don't want to regenerate and recompile the app to use new queries. I know that the generated query types are ultimately converted to string-based queries, but it doesn't seem that is exposed in the public API. Is there any way to use AWS AppSync with GraphQL string queries?

Comment: Patrick, A couple of ideas spring to mind 1) Roll your own client using a HTTP client library such as okHttp and use the approach shown here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/blob/310c27836a841c905cd32f950ad691d13d4d8674/aws-android-sdk-appsync/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/appsync/sigv4/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor.java#L108 for authz/authn. 2) Use the apollo android library.  The right answer would depend on your circumstances and the reasons as to why you need to operate at this level of the GraphQL protocol.

Comment: @Bommas The need for this arises in a cross platform app (JavaScript and native code). I need both the JS and native code to share the same Apollo client or at least the same cache object. My thought here was to have the JS code construct string-based queries and pass to the native client to execute, but that isn't possible. I ultimately had to drop AppSync / GraphQL altogether for this reason.